# Passing arguments to redirect_to in mojolicious and using them in the target controller

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I am passing arguments to redirect_to like

```
$c->redirect_to('named', foo => 'bar');
```

or

```
$c->redirect_to('named, query => {foo=> 'bar'});
```

but I am not sure how to use it or retrieve the value of foo in the target controller.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`$self->redirect_to('named', foo => 'bar')`, used without a preceding slash, refers to named routes, and parameters are placed into route placeholders.

Each route you define in your application gets assigned a route name by default, or you can assign them manually. (You can also get a list of assigned routes using `./myapp routes`)

In a lite app:

```
action # route name

get '/named' => sub { ... }; # named
get '/named/:foo' => sub { ... }; # namedfoo
get '/named/:foo' => sub { ... } => 'something-else'; # something-else
```

The following redirects to the `get '/named/:foo'` action:

```
$self->redirect_to('namedfoo', foo => 'bar')
```

Which is effectively the same as:

```
$self->redirect_to('/named/bar');
```

You can access the placeholder value within the action using ->param:

```
get '/named/:foo' => sub {
  my $self = shift;
  $self->render_text($self->param('foo'));
};
```

Which renders the following HTML:

`bar`

---

You might also want to check out:
http://mojocasts.com/e2#Generic%20Placeholders

Comment: If I want to pass more data to redirected page I should use `$self->session->{ data => [ 'z' ] }`  should not? and access that data in target controller `$self->session->{ data }[0]` #z

Answer (score 5):

[Very verbose explanation](http://corky.net/dotan/programming/mojolicious-request-parameters-example.html) how to pass and get `param`

> $self is a mojolicious controller. In each case, we call $obj->param for a list of names, $obj->param("arg") for the value (or list of values):

```
$self->param             -- params from route, post and get
$self->req->param        -- params from post and get
$self->req->query_params -- params from get
$self->req->body_params  -- params from post
```