# Mojolicious every_param not populating array for integers

Tags: perl, parameters, mojolicious

```
  my $warranty_dates  = $self->every_param('warranty_date');
  my $state_ids       = $self->every_param('state_id');
```

results in:

```
   $VAR1 = undef;
```

and

```
  $VAR1 = '12/12/2017';
  $VAR2 = '12/12/2017';
  $VAR3 = '12/12/2017';
  $VAR4 = '12/12/2017';
  $VAR5 = '12/12/2017';
```

respectively when called by

```
  die Dumper(@{$state_ids});

  die Dumper(@{$warranty_dates});
```

despite being shown as having the following parameters:

```
  "state_id" => [
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1
   ],
  "warranty_date" => [
    "12/12/2017",
    "12/12/2017",
    "12/12/2017",
    "12/12/2017",
    "12/12/2017"
```

Comment: How did you get the last output? This looks like you have a typo, or there is some invisible character in the `state_id`param. Maybe a `\0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found the answer, which is that I didn't address the parameters as post requests.

https://corky.net/dotan/programming/mojolicious-request-parameters-example.html

quick explanation of why some of these parameters need to be in the format

```
$self->req->every_param('');
```

[Passing arguments to redirect_to in mojolicious and using them in the target controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622247/passing-arguments-to-redirect-to-in-mojolicious-and-using-them-in-the-target-con)